# Java time stamp regular expression

Tags: java, regex, timestamp, removeall

Given the following time stamp generated by [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--):

```
2014-10-20 11:17:55.19
```

I need a "long type" time stamp (without the punctuation), so what regular expression could help to remove these characters:

```
'-', ':', ' ', '.'
```

So that I can get a result that looks like:

```
2014102011175519
```

Comment: Be aware that a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) resolves to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). So the fractional seconds in its string representation could have [as many as nine digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--). So your resulting string will vary in length across different values. That may be an issue for some apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all `\D` (non digits) with blank:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Or use a date format, since a java.sql.Timestamp is a Date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS");
String str = sdf.format(timestamp);
```

Comment: Also, in Java 8, the java.sql.Timestamp class has new methods such as [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--) for converting to objects in the new java.time package. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) preserves the nanoseconds contained in a `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replaceAll` function to remove `-`, `:`, , `.` characters from your input string.

```
String s = "2014-10-20 11:17:55.19";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[-: .]", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
2014102011175519
```

Answer (score 0):

`/([^\d])/g`

regex in replace function as

```
replaceAll("[^\d]","")
```

or more shortly

```
replaceAll("\D","")
```

Comment: `[^\d]` would be the same as simply `\D`. Shorthand character-classes with a capital letter are the negative versions of their lower-case counterparts. (so equally, `[^\w]` == `\W`)